# Hex Rays conversion

Tags: c++, c, x86, masm

How would someone get the actual location/address of result function 1002DDCC3 through offset in IDA PRO?
Specifically the "a1 + 0x2E0" part.

It calls a new function obviously sub_100xxxxx;

Let's say

```
a1 == 942691698;

int (__stdcall *__stdcall QueryInterface(unsigned int a1))(int)
{
 if ( a1 == 942691698 )
            return (int (__stdcall *)(int))sub_1002DDC3;
}

int __stdcall sub_1002DDC3(int a1, int a2)
{
  int result; // eax@2

  if ( a1 )
    result = (*(int (__stdcall **)(_DWORD))(*(_DWORD *)a1 + 0x2E0))(a2);
  else
    result = -1;
  return result;
}
```

Raw Assembly of the function 1002DDC3 is http://img.techpowerup.org/121010/Capture.png

Comment: The location of the function through offset? Which function? What does 'through offset' mean? `sub_1002DDC3` most likely is an address within a DLL based at `0x10000000` which would mean the function is offset `0x2DDC3` from the module base.

Comment: I already knew that however what does the 1002DDC3 return?
Specifically the 0x2E0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wording is very unclear. Assuming that `QueryInterface()` really does have something to do with `IUnknown::QueryInterface()`:

If you're asking "what is the meaning of the return value of `sub_1002DDC3()`", it's probably an [HRESULT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The most important values here are zero (`S_OK`), -1 (general error), and non-zero (specific errors).

Or are you asking "what is the address of `sub_1002DDC3()`?"

It would actually be *easier* to understand this if you could post the raw disassembly.

**Edited to add**

The address of the interface method is determined at runtime. The disassembler doesn't know the addresses in advance and so can't tell you which method is being called.

Yes, you need to disassemble the COM object separately.

Comment: "a1 + 0x2E0" calls an interface method through sub_1002DDC3(); however what is the position/address of it. I can't find it in IDA PRO.

Comment: I guess I need a COM DUMP IDA Plugin

Comment: Is there some unofficial guide to disassembling COM Objects?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the value of the 'a1' argument. Since this function can be called with different values of 'a1', it is impossible to tell by just looking at the listing. You will have to run it under a debugger or check the callers.